# Troubleshooting Issue: PHPUnit Phar File Not Executing Properly from "bin" Directory

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit

I'm encountering an issue with a Phar file, specifically PHPUnit. I've added it to a package within the "bin" directory. When I run vendor/bin/phpunit.phar, nothing happens, and there is no output. However, if I directly execute the file from its path, it works fine.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem?

I created a package specifically to try this out. It is wulfheart/phpunit-shim.

Comment: And when you don't run it directly, what is the command you enter? It's missing in your question. Also please add your composer.json to your question, as well as see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for some general remarks.

Comment: And do you have specific requirements regarding the PHP version? E.g. PHP 8.2 is fine? Why I ask: IIRC Composer has no bin-stub support for .phar files, but .php files. you could use a .php file that requires the phar file. This works since PHP 8.2 (or was it 8.1) without the need to crack the phar file open prior use (to remove the hashbang).